# razor add image with path not working asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Create.cshtml (add image part)

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="upload" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

full Create.cshtml

```
@model JobOfersWebSite.Models.job

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "jobs", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/from-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>job</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobDiscription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobDiscription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobDiscription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="upload" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategorieId, "Categorie", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CategorieId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategorieId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

JobController.cshtml

```
public ActionResult Create( job job,HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), upload.FileName);
        upload.SaveAs(path);
        job.JobImage = upload.FileName;
        db.jobs.Add(job);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The Problem in FR
La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.

Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code.

Détails de l'exception: System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.

Erreur source:

```
Ligne 54 :             if (ModelState.IsValid)
Ligne 55 :             {
Ligne 56 :                 string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), upload.FileName);
Ligne 57 :                 upload.SaveAs(path);
Ligne 58 :                 job.JobImage = upload.FileName;
```

Fichier source : c:\Users\DelManari\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\JobOfersWebSite\JobOfersWebSite\Controllers\jobsController.cs    Ligne : 56 
Trace de la pile:

> [NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.]
>          JobOfersWebSite.Controllers.jobsController.Create(job job, HttpPostedFileBase upload) in c:\Users\DelManari\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\JobOfersWebSite\JobOfersWebSite\Controllers\jobsController.cs:56
>          lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +147
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3f() +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() +228
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9986301
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue could be due to typo - 
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "jobs", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/**from-data**" }))

It should be enctype="multipart/**form-data**"